# How to overwrite node depth in JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit

Tags: javascript, infovis

[image: Please see attached image.]

At level 2 (0 is the centre), we have BTs and BDs.
I want to display BDs at level 3 and move ENs to level 4. It means that I need to somehow change those nodes depth.

http://www.ivangasparetto.com/jit-test

The custom js file is at http://www.ivangasparetto.com/jit-test/js/jit/jit-qorex.js

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide your data `Object` or parts of it?

Comment: Along the same lines as @AvL, please provide more information. What type of graph are you using? Or is this a `hypertree`?

Comment: There we go: http://www.ivangasparetto.com/jit-test/

The custom js file is at http://www.ivangasparetto.com/jit-test/js/jit/jit-qorex.js